# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in singly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm stuck with an issue with singly linked lists in C. Ive created a function which takes an index and an inventory of type singly linked lists. The function is supposed to take the element, which is at the index, out of the list and return one of its parameters. Here is my code:

```
int sellItem(int number, InvNode **inventory)
{
    struct invNode *current = *inventory;
    struct invNode *previous = *inventory;
    number += 1;
    if (inventory == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    else if (number == 1)
    {
        *inventory = current->next;
        return (current->value);
        free(current);
        current = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while (number != 1)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
            number--;
        }
        previous->next = current->next;
        return (current->value);
        free(current);
        current = NULL;
    }
}
```

It works okay for a while but then crashes and puts out the segmentation fault error. Also the index was originally starting from 0 but I've increased it by 1.

Comment: Some pretty fundamental concepts of C are unfortunately not in your wheelhouse, and they somewhat need to be for before you take on things like multi-level-indirection; like the fact that no code following a `return` will actually execute. Ex: neither of those `free(current); current = NULL;` will ever execute in the posted code.

Comment: Note : `if (inventory == NULL){` <<-- this test should be done **before** dereferencing the pointer. BTW: what is the *purpose* of this function?

Comment: If you're getting a core dump, you should examine it.  It will tell you exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a properly terminated linked list, your code has several flaws, including memory leaks and failure to properly null-check prior to evaluation.

In reality, what you're really trying to do is *probably* the following. Since you're given a pointer to pointer to node, you can use that to walk down the list, initially starting with whatever was passed in, and obtaining the address of each `next` member along the way until you arrive at the node you want to trim. The result is:

```
int sellItem(int number, InvNode **inventory)
{
    int res = -1;

    if (inventory)
    {
        while (*inventory && number-- > 0)
            inventory = &(*inventory)->next;

        if (*inventory)
        {
            InvNode *tmp = *inventory;
            *inventory = tmp->next;
            res = tmp->value;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

This assumes `inventory` holds the address of the head pointer of your linked list, passed from wherever. It also assumes `number` is zero-based. I.e. if you want the first element in the list to be unlinked, value-retained, and finally free'd, then for `number` you would pass `0` from the caller. The second node in the list would be `1`, etc. That's it.